# Do aspects caused by fallout grant tags?

Tags: dresden-files, fate

A powerful but unskilled sorcerer throws a fireball at Harry, but draws in more power than he can hope to control. Being a selfish, cowardly (ie, typical) villain he lets the power loose as fallout rather than taking stress from backlash. The GM rules that the fallout causes the room to be set *On Fire*.

- Does the *On Fire* aspect have a tag (free invocation) associated with it?
- If so, who does the tag 'belong' to? The sorcerer? The GM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Only Aspects deliberately placed by a character can be tagged for free. All others are just plain ol' Aspects, regardless of how or when they are created, and can be invoked or compelled in the usual way using Fate points.

Consequences are an exception because the rules make an explicit provision for that. They're the consequence of your attack, so it makes sense that you could immediately exploit them.

The **On Fire** aspect is not something anyone set about to cause, and everyone is equally surprised by its sudden impact on the scene—everyone has to put some effort into it, if they want to turn it to their advantage.